how to bypass TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
I'm encountering a problem while uploading my  application to AWS as an API. The AWS logs show the following error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

How can i bypass this type of error?
A step-by-step guide would be greatly appreciated.
error log
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: (node:25450) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at ResourceCacheService.refreshStudyAndConsultation (/var/app/current/src/resource/service/resource.cache.ts:314:97)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at ResourceCacheService.refreshCachePublicFacing (/var/app/current/src/resource/service/resource.cache.ts:98:5)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at ResourceCacheService.onModuleInit (/var/app/current/src/resource/service/resource.cache.ts:82:5)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at async Promise.all (index 0)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at Object.callModuleInitHook (/var/app/current/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:43:5)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at NestApplication.callInitHook (/var/app/current/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:169:13)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at NestApplication.init (/var/app/current/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:97:9)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: at NestApplication.listen (/var/app/current/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:156:33)
Sep  9 09:05:57 ip-172-31-32-56 web: (node:25450) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=stri`ct` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 61)

the code
private async refreshStudyAndConsultation() {
    let type = ResourceType.Service;
    let subType = ResourceSubType.Service;
    let advisoryBenefit = (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationAdvisoryBenefit))[0];
    let strategicBenefit = (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationStrategicBenefit))[0];

    let cachedData = {
      catalog: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultation))[0].url,
      mainPicture: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationMainPicture))[0].url,
      catalogMainPicture:(await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationCatalogMainPicture))[0].url,
      mainDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationMainDesc))[0].content,
      whyUsDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationWhyUsDesc))[0].content,
      methodDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationMethodDesc))[0].content,
      methodItem: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationMethodItem)).map((e) => {
        return {
          content: e.content,
          title: e.title,
        };
      }),
      quickLinks: await this.categoryService.findByPageName(QuickLinkPageName.StudyAndConsultation),

      advisoryBenefit: {
        content: advisoryBenefit.content,
        icon: advisoryBenefit.url,
      },
      advisoryDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationAdvisoryDesc))[0].content,
      advisoryItem: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationAdvisoryItem)).map((e) => {
        return {
          content: e.content,
          title: e.title,
        };
      }),

      strategicBenefit: {
        content: strategicBenefit.content,
        icon: strategicBenefit.url,
      },
      strategicDesc: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationStrategicDesc))[0].content,
      strategicItem: (await this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultationStrategicItem)).map((e) => {
        return {
          content: e.content,
          title: e.title,
        };
      }),
    };
    this.cacheManager.set(this.getKeyPublic(STUDY_AND_CONSULTATION), cachedData);
  }

I’m feeling stuck and not sure how to move forward. Could you please offer some assistance?


One of 'find's does not find anything.

it might be that the this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultation)) is undefined, so addeing the "?." null check will solve this
replace this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultation))[0].url
in this format this.find(type, subType.StudyAndConsultation))?.[0]?.url
